# Why AWS Aurora MySQL lets inset number bigger than 65

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

AWS Aurora MySQL. I have a table with column type DECIMAL.
When I try to insert or update number 1000**000 (66+symbols) it stores number - 999**999 (65 symbols);

If I try to do the same action in my local MySQl I get correct behavior - Error "Can't insert data. Value for filed is out of range."

I need to have same behavior and response in Aurora. How can I reach it?

Comment: provide the DDL  (Create table statements) for the table in both environments.

Comment: Check `SELECT @@sql_mode;` in both environments. I assume you have strict mode set on your local MySQL, but not on Aurora. If you set the SQL mode the same in both environments, I believe you will get the same behavior. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html for more information.